# CSS dropdown menu format issues

Tags: css, image, text, colors, hover

I need some help with a CSS dropdown menu. jsfiddle link below.

Two things I need help with. The first is how do I spread the 5 menu items out across the entire page? I tried this with ul li { margin-right: XXX } but before Item5 got all the way to the right side of the page it dropped down onto the next line. Any ideas?

Second thing. I am trying to change the colour of the text (in the jsfiddle it is blue), but when I change the text colour by adding a class to the text, the hover action to change the text to white does not work. How can I change the text colour ensuring the hover still works?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ghs

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the update to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ghs/3/
You got some typos (e.g. transition with a missing letter), I fixed them.

Font color is set to blue by browser, as an "" is styled as hyperlink, so you need to select this tag, e.g. with

```
ul li a{    color: orange; }
ul li a:hover{    color: yellow; }
```

I defined some demo colors, change them the way you like.

To force the 5 columns to span over the side, remove the margin-right and set for example

```
  ul li {
    margin: 0;
    width:19%;
  ... }
```

Somehow 20% does not work and column number 5 will break to next line, 19% will be fine.

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank dsuess for your reply. Unfortunately the:ul li a { color: orange } doesn't work. Change that color doesn't change anything, it seems like there is something blocking it from changing. As for the width:19%, it doesn't go across to the right far enough. Is there a padding on there preventing it from going all the way across? Sorry but I am new to html and css. Thanks.

Comment: do your links still appear blue? I checked the fiddle update number 3 ( http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ghs/3/ ) in latest chrome, firefox, ie10, opera and the links are not blue.
Item1-5 are orange and turn yellow on hover, Item3A-D are white turning green.
What browser and operation system do you use?

Comment: You have defined `ul{ text-align: left; }`. 
"width: 19%" means, each of your colums is 19% of the page width. If the content within a div is short (like the five characters of item1) there is much space to the rigth.
Of course you could set the last item (item5) to "text-align: right" like in fiddle #4 http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ghs/4/ , but this looks strange as the space between item4 and item5 is huge.

You could "text-align:center", but text lines with different length will look strange too.

(deleted line "display: none;" in ul li ul block to enable fade in /fade out for submenu)